# PIXY camera modul: how to get image data?

Tags: arduino, camera, discovery

i would like to know if there exists datasheet for pixy camera modul, official wiki pages are not worth much. For starter i am interested in getting image from this camera modul, in wiki pages there is only a hello world program that detects objects. How to get image data? (Arduino) (I would like to transfer this image data via UART to computer, i know about pixymoon)

I would also like to know if there exists port to stm discovery 32f4?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. I saw this in the pixy forums, hope it's enlightening:

"is it possible to use an Arduino or any other device in order to decode/transform USB video into analog? What is the video format that is fed into USB? Is it possible to cut into Pixy hardware before the signal is encoded into USB and extract the signal? Thank you.

Hello ####, 
I think analog video is a pretty high bandwidth signal with strict timing requirements. I doubt this is possible without adding significant complexity.

Edward (developer)"